# Parallelization of Multiple Delaunay Triangulations in Mathematica

Tags: parallel-processing, wolfram-mathematica, delaunay

I am trying to run a large number of "DelaunayTriangulation" routines from the Computational Geometry package in Mathematica. I have an array, "Lattice", which contains data for several thousand points in several thousand time-frames. (e.g. Lattice[[i]] indicates the ith time frame with ~10000 (x,y) coordinates).

I want to generate another large array, "Tri", with all the triangulation index data inside. For a serial calculation:

Tri=Table[DelaunayTriangulation[Lattice[[i]]],{i,imax}];

This calculation will take an exceptionally long time, so naturally, I wish to parallelize this computation:

Tri=Parallelize[Table[DelaunayTriangulation[Lattice[[i]]],{i,imax}]];

The problem lies here; usually, I would expect these individual triangulations to be divided  between the 16 cores I have and run in parallel, but I don't see this. The parallelization doesn't affect anything and the computation runs as if it were on a single core.

I'm sure my use of "Parrallelize" is correct, as it works with default Mathematica commands in other tables.

Is this an issue using the triangulaion routine? Or perhaps memory (although the serial calculation uses about >>1Gb of the 32Gb of RAM I have)? Any insight into this will be useful.

Comment: You probably need to `ParallelNeeds` the package first.  That said, this function is very slow and I recommend you use a different solution instead of parallelizing: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13437/12

Comment: @Szabolcs ParallelNeeds solved it, I was only using Needs before. The alternative method is indeed superior, thank you for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: I think [a much better solution](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DelaunayMesh.html) is coming soon :-)